# What's the best way to do Ruby gemspec creation and dependency management?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, gemspecs

Over the last few months, there have been a number of rapid developments in the state of Ruby dependency management and gem creation, to the point where I've been having trouble keeping up with everything.

- If I'm writing a new gem, what's the best tool for me to use to create my `gemspec`? Are there disadvantages of using this tool over competitors?
- I've used [Bundler](http://github.com/carlhuda/bundler) a few times on applications and for me it's been a lifesaver. Is the consensus that it is suitable for use with production apps? Are there quirks or idiosyncracies people should be aware of?

Links to resources you've used and have found helpful would also be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have much experience with this, but here are some resources I've found helpful:

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/135-making-a-gem
- http://yehudakatz.com/2010/04/02/using-gemspecs-as-intended/

Answer (score 0):

Stuff to look into:

- http://github.com/drnic/newgem
- http://github.com/technicalpickles/jeweler

I haven't used any of them for real work (but toyed around with both of them and liked Jeweler better)